# Recommended Way To Associate Command With Environment?

Tags: bash, command-line, environment-variables

Sometimes I find myself using software (which I don't have the permissions or patience to re-compile) which searches through my PATH looking for its dependencies at runtime, but these dependencies are not compatible with what I otherwise want my PATH to be. For example, I'm often writing python 3 on a cluster which I sometimes want to use c3 commands like `cexec`, but c3 wants the first python in my PATH to be python 2.

Specifying the needed temporary PATH like this, `PATH=/usr/bin cexec echo hello world`, works but is entirely too much typing. Putting something like

```
C3PREFIX=/usr/bin
alias cexec=$C3PREFIX cexec
alias cname=$C3PREFIX cget
alias cname=$C3PREFIX cpush
alias cname=$C3PREFIX cnames
... for all such commands needing a special environment.
```

in my shell config is an okay solution to the typing problem, but this requires applying the same low-level macro to everything requiring that environment. I imagine commands could be persistently associated with environments in a more systematic way which won't break (such macros sometimes show that they are hacks when executing complicated commands) and which is not as heavy-weight a solution as a container/virtual machine. Is there a standard solution to this problem?

Comment: [Virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)...

Comment: It looks like with virtual environments, there is global state which you switch in and out by running "source activate <env>" or "source deactivate <env>", correct? For workflows where different commands needing different pythons (or other things occuring in PATHs) are often interleaved, would this not involve typing a whole lot of environment switching commands?

Answer (score 2):

Create a sh (preferrably dash) wrapper around the executable where you set up the environment and then exec the target:

```
#!/bin/sh
ENVVAR=envvar exec ./target "$@"
```

Dash is quite efficient, and this only adds about .0005s to the startup time of the target on my machine.

The equivalent C wrapper won't be much faster than that:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       setenv("ENVVAR", "envvar", 1);
       execvp("./target", argv);
}
```

Comment: You'd want to pass the arguments along. Trivial in C, not so much with dash for argv[0] (you may prefer mksh, another lightweight shell that supports `exec -a`)